# Android Code Enhancement

Tags: android, performance

I am having a Common "Signin" page that contains "Username" and "Password" Field..

And i am having two Tab Bars namely 1. Deals 2.Account..and user can login through either Deals or Account..

If i login from Deals after successful login the page must be redirected to the Deals page and if Login in account page after succesful login the page must be redirected to Account page.

The logic i used is simply "FLAG CONCEPT"..

If user Login in Deals page i set initial "flag_deal=0" to say "flag_deal=1".. and in SignIn page i will check

```
       if(flag_deal==1){
          flag_deal=0;
           Redirect to Deal page..
       }else{
           Redirect to Account Page..
       }
```

Now its works properly, I want to know that whether this way of writing Coding is Efficient or any way available to handle such a situation..

Please suggest me better alternative if you people knows..

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic is nothing wrong, and too simple to harm efficiency.

But why you reset the flag "flag_deal=0" after entering the if branch? you may use this afterward.

I think all you should do is to carefully manage this flag variable.